# How can I add css to my other local web pages?

Tags: html, css, xampp

In my nav I have home, reservation, price, about me, and contact. I added new files naming all the nav names. How can I start adding css to the local web pages that I made? I want my clients to click on the (contact) and be directed to the local page where I have pictures and another text about the contact information.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, I think you are asking two different things. To add the CSS to all of your pages just type in their `<head>...</head>` this: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="example.css">`
Instead to redirect them to the page you want from the navbar, if you used an `<a>` tag you can just type it like this: `<a href="example.html">text</a>`